# email otp verification with reactjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I'm trying to create a registration page and I want otp verification after registering with an account.  like most registration these days where after you create an account somewhere then you are given an activation link and when you click on the link, your account gets activated, so that's what I want in my registration page too, but with an otp.

I want my registration to be like, after creating an account, if the api sends 'verifyemail' as response then we are redirected to the otp verification page but I'm not sure how do to implement that. that the otp page knows that the entered otp is for this very email that we just used to create an account in  my website. Shall we send the email as a prop in the  element in the registration.js file like

```
else if (response.data === "verifyemail") {
      return <Redirect to="/verifyOtp" email={this.state.email}/ />;
}
```

or am I doing it wrong?

this is the otp verify page

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
class VerifyOTP extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      otp: ""
    };
    this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
  }
  onchange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  performVerify = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = {
      emailid: this.props.email,
      otp: this.state.registrationotp
    };
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    const url = "/api/verifyemail";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result);
      if (result.data === "verified") {
        return <Redirect to="/dashboard/" />;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="otp"
          placeholder="emnter otp"
          onChange={this.onchange}
        />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" onClick={event => this.performVerify(event)}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default VerifyOTP;
```

I tried to translate this code from an angularjs code to reactjs code as it was previously made on angularjs

```
  $scope.register=function(){
        $scope.newuser={
            'username':$scope.name,
            'password':$scope.password,
            'email':$scope.emailid
        }
           return $http.post('/api/register',$scope.newuser).then(function(response,status){
           if(response.data=='redirect'){
               $window.location.href="/home";                        
           }else if(response.data=='verifyemail'){
            angular.element(document.querySelector('#verifyemailbtn')).click();                            
           }else {
            window.alert(response.data);
           }
           });
        }

    });
 $scope.verifyemailotp=function(){
        $http.post('/api/verifyemail',{'emailid':$scope.emailid,'otp':$scope.registrationotp}).then(function(response,status){
            if(response.data=='verified'){
                $window.location.href="/home";                                        
            }
        });
        }
```

I want to know if till what I have done is correct or not? and if there's any mistake then please show me where I'm wrong. also the whole code is also on codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-shirley-nn235

Comment: You can use redux or context to store email and later that page can access.

Comment: can't I do it like I did till now? is there something wrong in my code? I dont really want to use redux.

Comment: Does this part work `return <Redirect to="/dashboard/" />;` that's not inside a render function - it's in an event callback and you generally would not use components there - you could change `location.href` or something here?

Comment: yeah i just checked.. it's not working. how do I redirect from the register page to the verify otp page with props?

Comment: you want to redirect to `verifyOtp` when `response.data` is `verifyemail` right ???

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you were doing wrong:

with react-router we don't use `Redirect` component that can be used in render.
For programmatically changing route we have to use `history.push` or `history.replace` according to need.

so replace

```
<Redirect
    to={{
        pathname: "/verifyOtp",
        state: { email: "this.state.email" }
    }}
/>
```

with

```
this.props.history.push("/verifyOtp", { email: this.state.email });
```

There are difference b/w `params` and `state` state when you pass something to state you can access via `props.location.state` and if you want to change routing params that time you have to pass route in that way only i.e. `location.push('/verifyOtp?email=test')` this we have to access with `props.match.params.email`.

here is updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-turing-inx3w

other suggestions:

Don't use `var` use `const`, `let`

there is no diff b/w `onClick={event => this.performLogin(event)}` and `onClick={this.performLogin}` you can neglate unwanted function

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you show me how to wrap verifyOtp inside a privaterouter that it can be only accessed when the login details are correct with authentication in the sandbox?

Comment: You can use nested routes just check online you will get a lot of examples.